# Character encoding conversion to utf-8 in HTML form

Tags: html, forms, encoding, utf-8, internationalization

Could you please help me in sorting out a problem with character encoding?

I have a rich text box in an HTML form. User can either type or copy and paste text into it. Internally it preserves the value as HTML. Sometimes I get malformed HTML fragments, e.g.:

```
    <span lang="EN-US" style="font-size:12.0pt;font-family: " arial","sans-serif";
mso-fareast-font-family:ë°”íƒ•;mso-font-kerning:1.0pt;="" mso-ansi-language:en-us;mso-fareast-language:ko;mso-bidi-language:ar-sa"="">Hyun</span>
```

I guess it is because of some problem in character encoding. This typically happens if the user is from China, Japan or Korea.

By the way the first few lines from html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

I guess this happens because the user does a copy and paste into form, and his clipboard has a different encoding but the browser turns it into utf-8. I Is there something I am doing wrong? Any possibility of setting it right?

Thanks,
Srikanth

Comment: That HTML code (the `SPAN` tag) is not malformed. It's by design since all network data transfer is byte-based (instead of character-based). Your web server should treat all posted form data as UTF-8 encoded. i.e.: Read it as UTF-8 string so you'll get the actual foreign characters.

Comment: I believe the web server treats the POST data as UTF-8 encoded, because of the meta tag I have put in the head with charset set tp utf-8. I tried the following PHP code, and it resulted that the string is in UTF-8: print mb_detect_encoding($string, mb_detect_order(), true); I guess, there seem to be a conversion of encoding happens on the browser. So when the user pastes text from clipboard to the html form, a encoding conversion happens which converts from whatever encoding the original string was -> to utf-8, and that results in junk characters. I dont know how to set it right!